# How to create a command with a numerical name?

Tags: etoolbox, csname

I want to be able to do this:

```
\make{6}{hello!}
```

And it should turn into (`vi` is the roman for six):

```
\ifcsname foovi\else
  \newcommand\foovi{}
\fi
\gappto\foovi{hello!}
```

I'm doing this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\make[2]{
  \ifcsname make\romannumeral{#1}\endcsname\else
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname make\romannumeral{#1}\endcsname{}
  \fi
  \gappto\csname make\romannumeral{#1}\endcsname{#2}
}
\make{6}{hello!}
\makevi
\end{document}
```

I'm getting:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   {
l.10 \make{6}{hello!}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: \romannumeral must be followed by a TeX number, here you can remove the braces around (from {#1} to #1 ).

Comment: @plante still doesn't compile... can you please post a full answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeX is expecting a <number> after `\romannumeral`, so the braces are not allowed. Also, an `\expandafter` is needed for `\gappto`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\make[2]{%
    \ifcsname make\romannumeral#1\endcsname\else
        \expandafter\let\csname make\romannumeral#1\endcsname\empty
    \fi
    \expandafter\gappto\csname make\romannumeral#1\endcsname{#2}%
}

\make{6}{hello!}
\make{4}{foo}
\make{4}{bar}

\makevi\ \makeiv % hello! foobar

\end{document}
```